# Unable to make these loops count backward by using i-- to start at argc and count down to 0

Tags: c, while-loop, segmentation-fault

I have come across a tricky thing. This is the original program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // go through each string in argv

    int i = 0;
    while(i < argc) {
        printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
        i++;
    }

    // let's make our own array of strings
    char *states[] = {"cali","heo","arb","flu"};

    int num_states = 4;
    i = 0;  // watch for this
    while(i < num_states) {
        printf("state %d: %s\n", i, states[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The following is the question asked in the link :http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex11.html

> Make these loops count backward by using i-- to start at argc and count down to 0. You may have to do some math to make the array indexes work right.

For this question mentioned above, I made modifications to the above program.
In the following code I was able to execute only 1 while loop.
I am unable to execute both the loops.  Please rectify my code.

I have used `valgrind` tool for debugging.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 2;
    while(i < argc) {
        printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
        i--;
    }

    char *states[] = {
        "cali","heo","arb","flu"
    };

    int num_states = 4;
    i = 3;  // watch for this
    while(i < num_states) {
        printf("state %d: %s\n", i, states[i]);
        i--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ make while
$ ./while hey how
2 how 
1 hey 
0 ./while 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

and for the other way of output--

```
$ ./while
3 flu
2 arb 
1 heo 
0 cali 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

Hence my claim that I am "unable to execute both the while loops at once in the above way."  I have initialised `i=2` and it is decremented and I have reinitialised the `i` value to 3.

Comment: use `i = argc;` and `while(i)`. but to print them in order you have to do `argv[arc-i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had bad logic in the condition of the `while` loops  in the `while(i<argc)` and `while(i<num_states)` part. Change those to `while(i>=0)` or simply `while(i)` in both cases as due to the decrement `i--` it ultimately becomes 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i = 2;   // If OP is certain argc is 2!Better use i=argc instead
while(i >= 0)   //Error was  here 
{
    printf("arg %d: %s\n",argc-i, argv[argc-i]); // alteration here
    i--;
}


char *states[] = {
    "cali","heo","arb","flu"
};

int num_states = 4;
i = 3;  // watch for this
while(i >=0) {  //alteration here
    printf("state %d: %s\n", num_states-i, states[num_states-i]); // Here too
    i--;
}

return 0;}
```

**Caution:** The `while(i < num_states)` in your second program will surely cause a major trouble as the condition will  be satisfied each time,given `i` reduces by 1 after each iteration and `num_states` remain fixed at 4.

Comment: dont assume argc is 2 just assign it to `i`.:)

Comment: The OP seems to know before hand it's 2.Else generally I would write come code to see if argc matches with the number of arguments.

Comment: Argc is the number of arguments. How would you want to check it if it is the number of arguments?

Comment: @Redx If say 4 is the expected number of arguments to main(),then add a `if` block that produces a warning if the `argc!=4`

Comment: @Koushik Using `i=2` instead of `i=argc` is really improper indeed.But we were expected to point out the source of errors rather than to overhaul the whole program.

Comment: @SheerFish that is a part of the error finding process. the obvious error is how `i` is used (incremented or rather decremented). there is nothing wrong in overhauling the program for possible errors i believe. in a way you answer will become complete and be more informative to the OP(and others)

Comment: @Koushik That is why I make mentioned that in a comment in my program.And if the OP reads your comment,that again will clarify the whole thing for him.When I post a question,I read the comments more carefully than the answer :-)

Comment: @SheerFish  "I read the comments more carefully" right on spot :).

Comment: @All i'm more than happy to know the mistakes i hav made in the code..even if my code is not upto the mark,if someone finds somethng in the prog or optimisation is appreciated too... :).

Comment: @SheerFish couldnt vote up to the solution because my reputation level <15 .hope u can understand

Answer (score 1):

The idea for the loops is to start with `i` set to the maximum and to decrement `i` on each iteration:

```
i = argc;
while (--i >= 0)
    printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);

i = 4;
while (--i >= 0)
    printf("state %d: %s\n", i, states[i]);
```

Comment: maybe he wants to print them in the order he supplied them. using `argv[argc-i]` and `states[4-i]`is better i guess.

Comment: @Koushik nope,not in order but i jus wanted to execute the code by decrementing it,i was unable to execute both loops but solutions that are provided abve are working :)..like i was bothered abt segmentation fault thing..but wat i did was a silly mistake..:)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler couldnt vote up to the solution because my reputation level <15 .hope u can understand

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
while(i < num_states) { <---------------------- HERE
    printf("state %d: %s\n", i, states[i]);
    i--;
}
```

You are actually counting down and checking **incorrect** value.

Must be:

```
 while(i >= 0)
```

Here:

```
while(i < argc) {
    printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    i--;
}
```

The same:

```
while(i >= 0)
```

Comment: ya..this is the thng i missd..:)thank you for reminding me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int max = 4;
int i = max;
while(i > 0)
{
    // backward count
    cout << "state " << i << " " << states[i-1] << endl;
    printf("state %d %s\n", i, states[i-1]);

    // forward count
    cout << "state " << max-i << " " << states[max-i] << endl;
    printf("state %d %s\n", max-i, states[max-i]);
    i--;
}
```

Comment: What if argc != number of elements in states?

Comment: @RedX; then you have a faulty implementation of the compiler. :) After all, I was only addressing the example given, assuming that "states" is just a replacement for argv to make it more explizit in that particula example, and not that argc is actually refering to the number in states. I could have just as well used argv instead of states without changing the logic.

Comment: @Devolus it cant be a faulty compiler implementation. states is a type declared within the program argc can be/cannot be/need not be equal to the number of elements of the array states. first while loop deals with environment supplied variables. 2nd loop deals with locals.

Comment: I didn't intend to write the whole program, I just tried to show how the index has to be used. However, I changed the sample now renaming argc to max, which really makes a BIG difference. ;)

Comment: @Devolus yup i rectified it..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since the condition is

```
while(i < num_states)
```

and you are going to decrement i, this condition will be *always* (not always indeed) true. When i==-1, you are going to access `states[-1]` and you should prevent this.

The code should look like:

```
 i = num_states - 1;
 while (i >= 0)
```

This way you output the array in reverse order of course. To produce the same output, you could do something like the following instead:

```
int num_states = 4;
i = num_states - 1; 
while( (num_states - i - 1) < num_states) {
    printf("state %d: %s\n", num_states - i - 1, states[num_states - i - 1]);
    i--;
}
```

even though maybe it looks like an algebraic trick.

Comment: don't worry; it's enough to know I have been useful someway.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault is due to trying to call argv[i] (or states[i]) when i is negative, but that's because of a logic flaw with the loop structure.

For example, in the first loop:

```
int i = 2;
while(i < argc) {
    printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    i--;
}
```

Lets say argc is 4, for example. What your code does is tell the loop to repeat every time that i is less than 4. And, since i starts at 2 and goes down every time, this loop could repeat forever. The loop condition will always evaluate to true. However, since eventually i becomes negative and you try to use it as an array index, it creates a segmentation fault. The easiest way to fix it would be this:

```
int i = argc-1;
while(i >= 0) {
    printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    i--;
}
```

This way, i starts out at the last index of argv (which is argc-1 because argc is the number of elements in the array, and argv is the array starting with element 0. So for example if there argc was 5, this code would print argv[4] through argv[0])

I find the best way to think of a while loop is in basic english. "Keep repeating x while y is true". In your code, y is always true, so x keeps repeating forever (or, in this case, till a segmentation fault).

See if you can apply this logic to your other loop as well. Have fun learning c!

Comment: couldnt vote up to the solution because my reputation level <15 .hope u can understand

Comment: Hey, it's totally fine :) I'm glad I was able to help!